# Is a notification via Email possible with the integration of Stack Overflow in MS Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

We would like to integrate Stack Overflow in our MS Teams Environment.
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000739
Our company account is currently deactived so I can't test it myself.

Is it possible to have a summary of recent questions sent to the users email address? I know that there is a way of doing it via flow when there are messages in a certain channel. I don't know if the App offers support in this matter itself or if its possible to create a flow. If the latter a tutorial would be nice to have.

Comment: Currently Teams have StackOverflow connector which helps to post questions based on specified tags. But you can create stack App & integrate stack exchange API for our requirements